# to perform getmapping in springboot to get list of all details of all entities in a single api

Tags: java, spring-boot

my requirement is that I want to perform getmapping method in controller class such that the method should get the details of all the entities present in the package in a single call.

for example:
in controller class

```
    @GetMapping("/all")  //ALL
    public List<States> getAllCountry()
    {
        return service.findAllStates();
    }
```

it  gets all the details of the states present in the DB

my requirement is that I have 5 entity classes and till now I can perform findall method by extending the jpa repository to the interface and doing that

but now I need to perform all the findall method in a single get mapping method to get  all the entities list in a single ap call

Comment: you code looks fine, what exactly is your question? What do your entites look like? What JSON do you want to get as result? (btw, better call the endpoint `/states` if you return all states)

Comment: my question is -in entity package i have 5 classes i.e 1.states 2.country 3.document

Comment: The answer depend on how your entites are related. That's why I asked how your entity classes lokók like

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is a basic use case for the DTO design pattern.

In a sentence, you can create a service, that will call all your repositories, get all entities from each and create a new POJO, containing an entity from each repository(or more, depending on their relationship, as mentioned by @datz in the comments), and return it from the API. 
You can get a better understanding of DTO use-cases and how it works from this tutorial from [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-dto-pattern)